# Splitting a string in SQL Server according to requirement

Tags: sql, sql-server

Here is the input table which has a parent sku i.e `BOO3` and its child skus `BOO3L,BOO3S,BOO3M`. This is my code so far and I'm stuck here.

[image]

The `categories` and `url-key` column should be changed like in expected result. The `url-key` column should be lowercase, separated by `-` .

I want the output to look like this:

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like you need a couple of SQL Server functions for this.

First a test table with the data you gave:

```
CREATE TABLE [TestTable] 
([sku] VARCHAR(10), [product_type] VARCHAR(50), [categories] VARCHAR(100),
 [name] VARCHAR(255), [url_key] VARCHAR(255));

 INSERT INTO [TestTable]
 VALUES
 ('B003', 'configurable', 'Men''s PJs → Comical Boxers', 'Wanna Moose Around Comical Boxer', NULL),
 ('B003L', 'simple', 'Men''s PJs → Comical Boxers', 'Wanna Moose Around Comical Boxer', NULL),
 ('B003M', 'simple', 'Men''s PJs → Comical Boxers', 'Wanna Moose Around Comical Boxer', NULL),
 ('B003S', 'simple', 'Men''s PJs → Comical Boxers', 'Wanna Moose Around Comical Boxer', NULL);

 SELECT * FROM [TestTable];
```

For the categories, you'll need a [CHARINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186323.aspx#Anchor_0) or [PATINDEX()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188395.aspx#Anchor_0) to cut out the '→' (*alt + 26 apparently, I had to look it up*).

The URL's will need a [LOWER()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms174400.aspx#Anchor_0) to get rid of the Title Case and [REPLACE()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms186862.aspx#Anchor_0) to change the spaces to a hyphen.

Finally, your 'Small, Medium, Large' needs a mixture of [RIGHT()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-gb/library/ms177532.aspx#Anchor_0) to check what it is and a [CASE](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181765.aspx#Anchor_0) to add on the relevant suffix.

```
 SELECT 
        [sku]
    ,   [categories] = SUBSTRING([categories], CHARINDEX('→', [categories]) + 1, 1000)
    ,   [name]
    ,   [url-key] = CASE 
                        WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'L' THEN REPLACE(LOWER([name]), ' ', '-') + '-large'
                        WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'M' THEN REPLACE(LOWER([name]), ' ', '-') + '-medium'
                        WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'S' THEN REPLACE(LOWER([name]), ' ', '-') + '-small'
                        ELSE REPLACE(LOWER([name]), ' ', '-')
                    END
    FROM [TestTable]
    ORDER BY (CASE 
                WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'L' THEN 4
                WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'M' THEN 3
                WHEN RIGHT([sku], 1) = 'S' THEN 2
                ELSE 1
            END) DESC

DROP TABLE [TestTable];
```

Finally another CASE statement to get the `ORDER BY` right because, as far as I can tell, there is no natural way to order this the way you want.